# Why isn't my button click event being triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following js file:

```
var IOMaximizeButton = {
 setup: function () {
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log("maximize button was clicked!");
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  IOMaximizeButton.setup();
});
```

Here is the body of my HTML:

```
 <body>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Maximize</a>
    <iframe id='iframe-primary' name='iframe-primary' src='foo.html' />
    <iframe id='iframe-secondary' name='iframe-secondary' src='bar.html' />
    </body>
```

I want that javascript to execute when my button is clicked. But it doesn't seem to be triggering. Why?

I have imported my JS file at the bottom of the HTML page btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your object, `this` refers to the instance of the object itself, so you're trying to bind a click event to the JavaScript object, rather than a DOM element. I'm guessing you actually want something like this:

```
var IOMaximizeButton = {
 setup: function () {
    $("#yourButton").click(function(){
        console.log("maximize button was clicked!");
    });
  }
};
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Awgh/1/).

Comment: @SheehanAlam - See my edit, I've added a link to a working example.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Ideally, you'd pass the jQuery object into the setup function....

Comment: @JuanMendes - Yes, agreed. However the approach in my answer was intended to just illustrate why the OPs method was failing.

Answer (score 1):

you have not bind the button with the function

how the function will call as there is no code written to trigger the function when button is clicked

```
var IOMaximizeButton = {
    setup: function () {
        $("#button").click(function(){
        console.log("maximize button was clicked!");
      });
    }
};
<a href="#" id="button">Maximize</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `$("#maximize").click(` , and `<a id="maximize" ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not attached to any selector, so I cannot catch any events. $(this) is a blank object.

Try changing $(this) to some specific selectors.